# Renaming a downloaded file using wget

Tags: wget

Here is my wget command where i am trying to rename the file which i am downloading but it is not working. I am using -O option here but somehow it is not working.

access="http://mvn:8081/nexus/content/com/mvn/"

wget -r -np -nd -l1 -O "access.war" "$access" -A "com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.access.web-"$n"-*.*-1-ldm-access-web.war"

Here i am renaming it to access.war. I can only use wget to do this job due to some restrictions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: it says removing access.war since it should be rejected :(

Answer (score 0):

The option `-A` is "comma separated", but you are using dots to separate the extensions!

Instead of

```
-A "com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.access.web-"$n"-.-1-ldm-access-web.war"
```

Try

```
-A "com,infa,products,ldm,ingestion,access,web-"$n"-,-1-ldm-access-web,war"
```

If this is not the solution to your problem, I suggest you simplify your wget-call down to something like this

```
wget -r -np -nd -l1 -O "access.war" "$access"
```

Just to verify that all else is working.
Or even better (to get fewer files)

```
wget -r -np -nd -l1 -O "access.war" "$access" -A "war"
```